# Can I enable/disable ContentProvider programmatically?

Tags: android

In my application I have a `ContentProvider`.

Can I enable/disable it programmatically?

I need that provider only in certain flavors of my application and so I thought I, probably, could disable/enable it based on some other properties I have.

Comment: If by "flavors" you mean different distribution channels or something like that, you could also consider just not shipping the `ContentProvider` in the first place, using Gradle for Android's product flavors. Otherwise, Brigham's answer will work if you need to control the behavior of the provider in just a single APK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting`:

```
ComponentName conProvCN = 
    new ComponentName(aContext, "com.a.content.provider.AContentProvider");
PackageManager pm = aContext.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(conProvCN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```